# How to calculate means by rows from several tables in R?

Tags: r, list, rows

I have several data sets with x,y,z coordinates and a time stamp. I loaded the individual data files into a single object which looks something like this:

```
    [[1]]
    x;y;z;time
    -3.144;0.8554;-1.806;0.0724
    -3.144;0.8554;-1.806;0.0968
    -3.144;0.8554;-1.806;0.6275
    -3.144;0.8554;-1.806;0.6484
    -3.144;0.8554;-1.806;0.6611 
    ...
    [[2]]
    x;y;z;time
    -2.840;0.9775;-2.058;0.0724
    -2.832;0.9775;-2.058;0.0968
    -2.845;0.9775;-2.062;0.6275
    -2.833;0.9775;-2.067;0.6484
    -2.847;0.9775;-2.070;0.6611 
    ...
```

Now I want to write a new table that calculates the mean for x, y, z of each of the data files for each time stamp. So it would look something like this:

```
x.mean;y.mean.;z.mean;time
-2.992;0.916;-1.932;0.0724
-2.988;0.855;-1.806;0.0968
...
```

Is there a function/package that can do this? I have tried the multiple package but did not find a solution there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.table` might be effective here. I am assuming your object is a list of data.frame tables, and it is called `yourlistobject`.

```
library(data.table)

#Convert data to data.table and then stack all data onto of one another
big.list <- lapply(yourlistobject,setDT)
big.data <- rbindlist(big.list,fill=TRUE)

#Calculate means by timestamp
out <- big.data[, lapply(.SD,mean,na.rm=T), by=.(time)]
out
```

Comment: `rbindlist()` also works with list-of-lists and data.frames. So the first step isn't necessary IIUC.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick and dirty approach that should work.

```
iris1 = iris
iris2 = iris

iris1$Name = 'file1'
iris2$Name = 'file2'
iristotal = rbind(iris1,iris2)

data <- subset(iristotal, select= -c(Species, Name))
names <- subset(iristotal, select= c(Name))
aggregate( data,names, mean)
```